# Ternary operator with variable substitution in HTML

Tags: html, angularjs

In a side panel of an app I want to either display "enabled" or "disabled" and I know I can write two different ng-if statements, but I wanted to see if there was a clever way to do it in just single line.

For reference here is what I have that works right now:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div class="rightColumn" ng-if="selectedProject.backupEnabled">Enabled</div>
<div class="rightColumn" ng-if="!selectedProject.backupEnabled">Disabled</div>
```

This isn't super critical obviously, but would be neat to know more about

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
<div class="rightColumn">{{ selectedProject.backupEnabled ? 'Enabled' : 'Disabled' }}</div>
```

This will work.

Comment: if you remove the ``ng-if="selectedProject.backupEnabled"`` it might :P

Comment: The parenthesis are useless too. And there's also an "Enabled" after the interpolation which is not needed.

Comment: And the `Enabled` string after the expression. Else I'd assume you would end up showing either `EnabledEnabled` or `DisabledEnabled`

Comment: Yup! That one should go too

Comment: Yes, you're absolutely correct, this did work! Thank you! I'll accept the answer once Stackoverflow lets me (:

Comment: @LeonardoChaia Thanks for pointing out. Did some typo mistake while typing.

Comment: Nice @slacker, just didn't wanted to answer the same thing. I think there's no other way to do it.